# Python LinkedList yield

Tags: python

i'm trying to make an 'append' method but i'm getting this error:

```
FAIL LinkedList/Combining [1] with [] yields list of length 1
Exception TypeError raised: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'LinkedList' and 'NoneType'
  File "<string>", line 104, in _
```

i'm not sure what 'yields' actually is or how to use it in this context. This is what is tried to do:

```
def __init__(self,value,next=None):
    self.__value=value                          
    self.__next=next

    def __append__(self,lst):
    if self.next is None:
        yield  LinkedList(value,lst)
    else:
        self.head= lst + self.next
    yield self.head
```

This is what i'm trying to do in Java:

```
public LinkedList append(LinkedList lst)
{
    if ( next == null )
    {
        return new LinkedList(value, lst);
   }
    else
    {
        return new LinkedList(value, next.append(lst));
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.next` -> `self.__next`?

Comment: I think you want to implement `__add__`, not `__append__`. The `+` operator calls the defined `__add__` method. I don't think `__append__` will do anything to the behaviour of any operators.

Comment: The "yields" looks like it's part of a test case name; you shouldn't actually use `yield` here.

Answer (score 0):

`yield` is only used in generator contexts. 
In a normal function, you'd just return a value with `return val` since only 1 value is being returned.

Also, if you want to use the `+` operator, the correct method is `def __add__(self, other)`

## Some brief information about generators if you're interested

The following function is a generator function:

```
def yieldNumbers(limit);
    for i in range(limit):
        yield i
```

Generators are useful as they allow you to ask for values one by one. This is in opposition to the following:

```
def listNums(limit)
    r = []
    for i in range(limit):
        r.append(i)
    return r
```

Here, the function generates ALL values and returns them ALL at once. This is a problem when dealing with large amounts of data as it can use of lots of memory. In contrast, generators, as I said yield values 1 by 1, and only when called: so the generator function yields one value and remembers its position in the loop and continues from where it left off. Consider the following:

```
def printNums((:
    print(1)
    yield 
    print(2)
    yield
    print(3)
    yield

>>> n = printNums()
>>> next(n)
1
>>> next(n)
2
>>> next(n)
3
>>> next(n)
StopIteration # that's an error raised when there's
# no more values left to yield
```

Generators use the `next(gen)` method which calls a generator's `gen.__next__()` internal method. This is useful if you want to implement an object that behaves like an iterator. However if you want to accomplish this, you should define method called `__iter__` which usually just returns `self`